# Finding the original positions of words in a sentence when the word occurs more than once

Tags: python

I need to find the positions of words in a sentence the user inputs and if the word occurs more than once, only print the first time that word occurs

I have the code so far-

```
sentence=input("Enter a sentence: ")
sentence=sentence.lower()
words=sentence.split()
place=[]

for c,a in enumerate(words):
    if words.count(a)>2 :
        place.append(words.index(a+1))
    else:
        place.append(c+1)

print(sentence)
print(place)
```

But it prints the positions of the individual words in the sentence rather than repeating a original position of a word that occurs more than once

Can anyone help me with this???

Comment: Your question is unclear; maybe an example or two would help.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using python 2, then `raw_input` instead of `input` else it'll eval.  That isn't a problem, just an observation (you're probably using python 3 then, so I'll leave it that way).

You could create a dict to track word counts and positions found. This is basically a dict of lists.  The dict being a map of words to a list of positions.

```
sentence=input("Enter a sentence: ")
sentence=sentence.lower()
words=sentence.split()

place={}
for pos, word in enumerate(words):
    try:
        place[word].append(pos)
    except KeyError:
        place[word] = [pos] 

print(sentence)
print(place)
```

Also, if you wanted to do something a little more advanced with your sentence parsing, you could do:

```
import re
words = re.split('\W+',sentence)
```

Basically uses all nonalphanumerics (commas, colons, etc) as a split.  Just note you can get a blank entry this way (probably at the end).

Comment: `raw_input` was removed in python3.

Comment: @Arnial Ahh, I'm still  using 2.7.  I'll update.  One day soon I'll get with the times.  Thanks :-)

Comment: @woot, I think the OP wants an output similar to the one in my answer. >>>*But it prints the positions of the individual words in the sentence rather than repeating a original position of a word that occurs more than once*. What do you think?

Comment: Oh, I think I understand. Instead of just the first position... print unique words and a list of positions that they were found in. That's easy enough, I edited it. It's flexible enough to take out or add little things like that I think.

Comment: Although with a list of position, count is superfluous so I guess I'll remove it

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs some modifications to achieve what you are trying to do:

- `if words.count(a)>2` : It should be `if words.count(a)>1` since count would be more than 1 if the word is repeated.
- `place.append(words.index(a+1))` : It should be `place.append(words.index(a)+1)` since you want to find the index of a and then add 1 to it.

**The modified code based on the suggestions:**

```
sentence=input("Enter a sentence: ")

sentence=sentence.lower()
words=sentence.split()
place=[]


for c,a in enumerate(words):
    if words.count(a)>1 :
        place.append(words.index(a)+1)
    else:
        place.append(c+1)

print(sentence)
print(place)
```

**Output:**

> ```
> Enter a sentence: "hello world hello people hello everyone"
> hello world hello people hello everyone
> [1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 6]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string

```
>>> s = '''and but far and so la ti but'''
>>> s = s.split()
>>> s
['and', 'but', 'far', 'and', 'so', 'la', 'ti', 'but']
```

use `set` to find the unique words and use the `list.index` method to find the first position of each unique word.

```
>>> map(s.index, set(s))
[0, 5, 2, 1, 4, 6]
```

`zip` the result of that with the unique words to associate the word with its position.

```
>>> zip(set(s),map(s.index, set(s)))
[('and', 0), ('la', 5), ('far', 2), ('but', 1), ('so', 4), ('ti', 6)]
>>>
```

---

I suppose a list comprehension might be easier to read;

```
>>> s = '''and but far and so la ti but'''
>>> s = s.split()
>>> result = [(word, s.index(word)) for word in set(s)]
>>> result
    [('and', 0), ('la', 5), ('far', 2), ('but', 1), ('so', 4), ('ti', 6)]
>>>
```

---

Sort on position

```
>>> import operator
>>> position = operator.itemgetter(1)
>>> result.sort(key = position)
>>> result
[('and', 0), ('but', 1), ('far', 2), ('so', 4), ('la', 5), ('ti', 6)]
>>>
```